# Overriding systemProperties in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have a bit of code that looks like this:

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['TARGET_ENVIRONMENT']?: 'qa'}")
private String environment;
```

In my integration tests, this property is always blank, and I can't seem to do anything to give it definition. I tried doing something like this in my integration tests to simply override the target environment attribute to something else:

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    System.setProperty("TARGET_ENVIRONMENT", "I love dogs");
}
```

But that didn't really work out.

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    System.setProperty("TARGET_ENVIRONMENT", "qa"); -> Not I love Dogs
}

@Value("$peopleSearch{key}") -> Defined as per properties file
private String peopleSearch;

@Value("$peopleSearch{address}") -> Defined as per properties file
private String address;
```

But that doesn't really change anything. I have other properties (as above) which are being defined in properties files that work out ok and get values, but this one seems to be using the systemProperties attribute, which I have no idea how/where to modify. What do I do to override systemProperties attributes?

Answer (score 0):

`systemProperties` isn't a function but variable. And it's initialized at the time Spring context is loaded. That's why setting system properties in runtime doesn't effect in your tests. [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) you can find more details of SpringEL.

You can pass the system property `-DTARGET_ENVIRONMENT` to the runner of the test. For example, if you run the test in an IDE (Eclipse or IntelliJ), you can pass it under JVM arguments of the Run Configurations. Or if you run it by Maven, see [this](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html).